java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't stop StopWatch: it's not running
The clock has been part of existing common logging functionality which consist filter where it starts based on the task name. My understanding here is clock has never started which resulted in this error. How to make sure its started.
override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
    val stopWatch = StopWatch().apply { start() }

    val headersToLog = exchange.request.headers.toSingleValueMap()
        .entries
        .filter { reqHeadersToLog.contains(it.key.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())) }
        .associate { it.key to it.value }

    fun handleReturn(pubStatus: String) {
        stopWatch.currentTaskName()?.let { stopWatch.stop() }
        val statusCode = exchange.response.statusCode?.name ?: "UNKNOWN_STATUS"

        logger.info(
            json.encodeToString(
                with(exchange.request) {
                    AccessLogEntry(
                        httpMethod = method?.name ?: "UNKNOWN_METHOD",
                        requestedUri = path.pathWithinApplication().value(),
                        httpStatusCode = statusCode,
                        durationMillis = stopWatch.totalTimeMillis,
                        host = remoteAddress?.hostString ?: "UNKNOWN_HOST",
                        pubStatus = pubStatus,
                        requestHeaders = headersToLog,
                    )
                }
            )
        )
    }

  
}


)}

Below is exception.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't stop StopWatch: it's not running
    at org.springframework.util.StopWatch.stop(StopWatch.java:154)
    at se.atg.caspr.commons.spring.webflux.AccessLoggingFilter.filter$handleReturn(AccessLoggingFilter.kt:32)
    at se.atg.caspr.commons.spring.webflux.AccessLoggingFilter.filter$lambda-7(AccessLoggingFilter.kt:54)
    at 


I guess you are not always start it before stopping

You are using a non-threadsafe class in a multi threaded environment. Don't. The start and stop for the StopWatch can be handled by multiple threads and as it isn't designed for that it might not have propagated the values to other thread stack yet. So don't use the StopWatch like that/for that.

What's on se.atg.caspr.commons.spring.webflux.AccessLoggingFilter.kt line 32?

updated question found common code
